# Parsing in C# using JSON.Net (very confusing!)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to parse the following JSON:

```
{"0":{"igloo_id":"0","name":"Igloo Removal","cost":"0"},"1":{"igloo_id":"1","name":"Basic Igloo","cost":"1500"},"2":{"igloo_id":"2","name":"Candy Igloo","cost":"1500"},"3":{"igloo_id":"3","name":"Deluxe Blue Igloo","cost":"4000"},"4":{"igloo_id":"4","name":"Big Candy Igloo","cost":"4000"},"5":{"igloo_id":"5","name":"Secret Stone Igloo","cost":"2000"},"6":{"igloo_id":"6","name":"Snow Igloo","cost":"1000"},"8":{"igloo_id":"8","name":"Secret Deluxe Stone Igloo","cost":"5000"},"9":{"igloo_id":"9","name":"Deluxe Snow Igloo","cost":"3000"},"10":{"igloo_id":"10","name":"Bamboo Hut","cost":"3200"},"11":{"igloo_id":"11","name":"Log Cabin","cost":"4100"},"12":{"igloo_id":"12","name":"Gym","cost":"4800"},"13":{"igloo_id":"13","name":"Split Level Igloo","cost":"4600"},"14":{"igloo_id":"14","name":"Candy Split Level Igloo","cost":"4600"},"15":{"igloo_id":"15","name":"Snowglobe","cost":"3700"},"16":{"igloo_id":"16","name":"Ice Castle","cost":"2400"},"17":{"igloo_id":"17","name":"Split Level Snow Igl","cost":"4600"},"18":{"igloo_id":"18","name":"Fish Bowl","cost":"2400"},"19":{"igloo_id":"19","name":"Tent","cost":"2700"},"20":{"igloo_id":"20","name":"Jack O' Lantern","cost":"2700"},"21":{"igloo_id":"21","name":"Backyard Igloo","cost":"4200"},"22":{"igloo_id":"22","name":"Pink Ice Palace","cost":"2400"},"23":{"igloo_id":"23","name":"Ship Igloo","cost":"4300"},"24":{"igloo_id":"24","name":"Dojo Igloo","cost":"1300"},"25":{"igloo_id":"25","name":"Gingerbread House","cost":"2100"},"26":{"igloo_id":"26","name":"Restaurant Igloo","cost":"4800"},"27":{"igloo_id":"27","name":"Tree House Igloo","cost":"4500"},"28":{"igloo_id":"28","name":"Theatre Igloo","cost":"4600"},"29":{"igloo_id":"29","name":"Circus Tent","cost":"0"},"30":{"igloo_id":"30","name":"Snowy Backyard Igloo","cost":"3000"},"31":{"igloo_id":"31","name":"Cave Igloo","cost":"1500"},"32":{"igloo_id":"32","name":"Green Clover Igloo","cost":"2050"},"33":{"igloo_id":"33","name":"Grey Ice Castle","cost":"2400"},"35":{"igloo_id":"35","name":"Cozy Cottage Igloo","cost":"2500"},"36":{"igloo_id":"36","name":"Estate Igloo","cost":"2500"},"37":{"igloo_id":"37","name":"In Half Igloo","cost":"2300"},"38":{"igloo_id":"38","name":"Shadowy Keep","cost":"2400"},"39":{"igloo_id":"39","name":"Dragon's Lair","cost":"3000"},"40":{"igloo_id":"40","name":"Mermaid Cove","cost":"3030"},"41":{"igloo_id":"41","name":"Whale's Mouth","cost":"2700"},"42":{"igloo_id":"42","name":"Trick-or-Treat Igloo","cost":"2000"},"43":{"igloo_id":"43","name":"Deluxe Gingerbread House","cost":"0"},"45":{"igloo_id":"45","name":"Invisible Snowy","cost":"0"},"46":{"igloo_id":"46","name":"Invisible Beach","cost":"0"},"47":{"igloo_id":"47","name":"Invisible Forest","cost":"0"},"48":{"igloo_id":"48","name":"Invisible Mountain","cost":"0"},"49":{"igloo_id":"49","name":"Shipwreck Igloo","cost":"900"},"50":{"igloo_id":"50","name":"Wildlife Den","cost":"900"},"51":{"igloo_id":"51","name":"Medieval Manor","cost":"1200"},"52":{"igloo_id":"52","name":"Warehouse","cost":"950"},"53":{"igloo_id":"53","name":"Pineapple Igloo","cost":"0"},"54":{"igloo_id":"54","name":"Creepy Cavern","cost":"1500"},"55":{"igloo_id":"55","name":"Frost Bite Palace","cost":"0"},"56":{"igloo_id":"56","name":"Fresh Baked Gingerbread House","cost":"2500"},"57":{"igloo_id":"57","name":"Penthouse","cost":"4000"},"58":{"igloo_id":"58","name":"VIP Penthouse","cost":"0"},"59":{"igloo_id":"59","name":"Invisible Age of Dinosaurs","cost":"0"},"60":{"igloo_id":"60","name":"Puffle Tree Fort","cost":"0"},"61":{"igloo_id":"61","name":"Secret Base","cost":"1600"},"62":{"igloo_id":"62","name":"Death Star Igloo","cost":"1000"},"63":{"igloo_id":"63","name":"Beach Party Igloo","cost":"1500"},"64":{"igloo_id":"64","name":"Gymnasium Igloo","cost":"0"},"65":{"igloo_id":"65","name":"Magical Hideout","cost":"1500"},"66":{"igloo_id":"66","name":"Eerie Castle","cost":"2000"},"67":{"igloo_id":"67","name":"Sweet Swirl Igloo","cost":"0"},"68":{"igloo_id":"68","name":"Train Station Igloo","cost":"1100"},"69":{"igloo_id":"69","name":"Main Event Igloo","cost":"1000"},"70":{"igloo_id":"70","name":"CP Airliner","cost":"1200"}}
```

I need a way to retrieve *igloo_id*, *name* and *cost*.

I've tried the following, but it's not what I want

```
List<Igloo> igloosList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Igloo>>(itemJson);
```

This is the structure of my class

```
namespace Canvas
{
    public class Igloo
    {
        public int cost;
        public int igloo_id;
        public string name;

        public int Cost
        {
            get
            {
                return cost;
            }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return igloo_id;
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error when trying to parse your Json as a List ? Because your Json contains an object containing several properties (property "0", "1", "2"). It should be an array.

Comment: I have a Dictionary<int, Igloo> where the key is igloo_id and Igloo is.. Igloo. I was trying to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to create a List object so I could iterate through it and add the igloo's id and object to the dictionary.

Comment: I do not  get an error.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want. The code you posted generated an exception when I tried running it, `Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[ConsoleApplication2.Program+Igloo]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.`. It did deserialize correctly if I used `var igloosList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Igloo>>( json );`. If you want to loop through it you could then use `foreach( var ig in igloosList.Values)`

Comment: @CraigW. You should make your comment an answer so Arthur can accept it.

Comment: I took my comment and rewrote it as an answer. I didn't do that in the first place because I really wasn't sure if it was answering the question because I didn't understand what the OP was actually asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want. The code you posted generated an exception when I tried running it,

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[ConsoleApplication2.Program+Igloo]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

It did deserialize correctly if I used:

```
var igloosList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Igloo>>( json );
```

If you want to loop through it you could then use:

```
foreach( var igloo in igloosList.Values )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JsonProperty` attribute :

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cost")]    
public int Cost
    {
        get
        {
            return cost;
        }
        private set { cost = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "igloo_id")]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return igloo_id;
        }
        private set { igloo_id = value; }
    }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        private set { name = value; }
    }
```

Basically you need to say for each property what is the Json key that will match. Plus, you will need to have a setter for each of your property, but it can be private.

Comment: A member with the name 'cost' already exists on 'Canvas.Igloo'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.